# Openerp Base report designer add a new field from a different object (base_report_designer)

Tags: openerp-7, openoffice-writer

In purchase order order.swx I need to show a new field(ean13) in line items rows, which comes from product.product object. How can I do it using base_report_designer and openoffice writer?

I have seen fields taken from taxes field like

```
[[ ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, line.taxes_id)) ]]
```

however if I try with product_id as relation to product object in the following way:

```
[[ ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.ean13, line.product_id)) ]]
```

it doesnt work. I am a newbie. Help me here!! 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
[[ line.product_id.ean13 ]]
```